# настройка apache 2 Yii ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, yii2, apache2

по адресу var/www/ создал diary.lc/ по адресу /etc/apache2/sites-available/ создал diary.lc.conf с такими параметрами

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName diary.lc
        ServerAlias www.diary.lc
        DocumentRoot /var/www/diary.lc
        <Directory /var/www/diary.lc/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

по адресу /var/www/diary.lc закачал и установил yii2 advanced
там поставил .htaccess

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    IndexIgnore */*
    RewriteEngine on

    # Если запрос начинается с /admin, то заменяем на /backend/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
    RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /backend/web/$1

    # Если запрос начинается с /api, то заменяем на /rest/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
    RewriteRule ^api\/?(.*) /rest/web/$1

    # Добавляем другой запрос /frontend/web/$1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend/web|backend/web|rest/web|admin|api)
    RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/web/$1

    # Если frontend запрос
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php

# Если api запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/rest/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /rest/web/index.php

# Если backend запрос
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php
```

в браузере в вожу diary.lc выводится стартовая страница apache2 если ввожу diary.lc/frontend/web/ ошибка 404

вот настройки urlmanager

```
'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            'index' =>'frontend/web/index',
            '<action>'=> 'site/<action>',
            ]
        ],
```

вот логи

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2016:15:00:12 +0300] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3688 "http://diary.lc/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

подскажите в чем проблема

Comment: «смотрите логи»™.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2016:15:00:12 +0300] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3688 "http://diary.lc/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"  вот логи

Comment: нет ничего о 404-й ошибке, про которую вы упоминаете.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вот по 404 ошибке  127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2016:15:00:27 +0300] "GET /frontend/web/ HTTP/1.1" 404 500 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"